# Why XML Response using Jersey REST Web service deployed on Tomcat 8 is taking more time with increased load

Tags: java, performance, rest, tomcat, jersey

Why XML Response using Jersey REST Web service is taking more time with increased load (deployed on Tomcat 8 inside Docker Container hosted on a Virtual Machine).

The actual processing time of the service is taking same/less time around 12-20 Milliseconds, but in the Tomcat access log while printing the Time taken to process the request, its taking with more load sometimes 200~250 in Milliseconds.
With initial low load all is fine. The Tomcat connections are already fine tuned to the appropriate threads etc.

**Versions:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Tomcat 8 
**Code Snippet:**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;            

    @POST
    @Path("/xml")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public MyResponse processRequest(MyRequest request) {
        long starttime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        MyResponse response = business logic using request goes here

        long endtime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        response.setProcessingTime(endtime - starttime);
*//This ProcessingTime looks okay, but while the response is automatically unmarshalled by Jersey API and send over, the Tomcat access log shows more time to process the request. From other monitoring tool also we see the same pattern.*

        return response;

    }
```

**Some High Response stacks: May not be the root cause.**

```
    java.lang.Thread:run:745 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
     HTTPServlet:service:729 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
      com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer:service:733 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer:service:558 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent:service:409 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
         com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl:handleRequest:1409 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
          com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl:handleRequest:1419 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl:_handleRequest:1473 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
            com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl:_handleRequest:1542 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
             com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule:accept:84 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
              com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule:accept:147 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
               com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule:accept:108 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
                com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule:accept:147 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
                 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule:accept:302 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
                  REST Service - com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher:dispatch:75 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
                   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker:_dispatch:203 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 365 ms)
                    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker:getParams:153 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 358 ms)
                     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider:getInjectableValues:86 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 358 ms)
                      com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable:getValue:123 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 358 ms)
                       com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest:getEntity:490 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 358 ms)
                        com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider:readFrom:111 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 358 ms)
                         **com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider:readFrom:115 (method time = 358 ms, total time = 358 ms)**
```

Comment: Any help on this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you really asking why things go slower during times of increased load?

Comment: Yes. We have fine tuned the GC and the application runs fine on 1 server with more than 150 TPS easily (respone time 20 Milliseconds), but when we are testing on 10 different servers with a load balancer, the TPS is not going beyond 30-40 on each server.The response time increses after more load is applied to almost 2 seconds. The load balancer is balancing load on all 10 servers evenly.

Comment: Maybe your load-balancer can't handle the load.

Comment: We have tried without load balancer also but same result.

Comment: So your app on Tomcat can respond within 20ms or so, but adding the lb raises that to 200ms or so, then removing the lb it is still 200ms? Or you are saying that "under load, the performance of our application on Tomcat drops by an order of magnitude"?